# What happens when a coroutine raises an exception?

Tags: python, coroutine

I'm not sure what exactly happens in the following piece of code:

```
def coroutine():
    lst = []
    try:
        while True:
            item = (yield lst)
            if item == 3:
                raise ValueError
            print('append {}'.format(item))
            lst.append(item)
    except GeneratorExit:
        print('GeneratorExit')

crt = coroutine()

next(crt)
print(crt.send(1))
print(crt.send(2))

try:
    print(crt.send(3))
except ValueError:
    pass

print(crt.send(4))
```

This outputs:

```
append 1
[1]
append 2
[1, 2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents and Settings\Brecht\Desktop\crt.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(crt.send(4))
StopIteration
```

When stepping through the code with a debugger, on `raise ValueError`, execution jumps to `except GeneratorExit:`, but the body of this except clause is not executed ('GeneratorExit' is not printed). Why not?

Aside from that, I don't suppose I can in any way resume the coroutine after it has thrown an exception? Is there any particular reason not to allow this? This would be useful at least in my particular use case :)

Comment: It jumps there but doesn’t execute it because it’s a `ValueError`?

Comment: @minitech doh, of course!

Answer (score 4):

When you throw an exception, the code flow is *always* interrupted. You cannot resume an interrupted generator once you throw an exception in it.

From [PEP 342 (Coroutines via Enhanced Generators)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/):

> As with the `next()` method, the `send()` method returns the next value
>       yielded by the generator-iterator, or raises `StopIteration` if the
>       generator exits normally, or has already exited.  If the generator
>       raises an uncaught exception, it is propagated to `send()`'s caller.

As for the debugger jumping to the `except` line: you just threw an exception and the interpreter is testing if the exception is caught by that line or not. Because it'll only catch a `GeneratorExit`, the generator exits at that point.

Comment: Would there be any harm in being able to resume the coroutine after the exception?

Comment: @BrechtMachiels *Where* would it resume? And in what state?

Comment: @BrechtMachiels: What if the exception was due to a conversion error (`int()` on a non-integer string value, `IndexError` on a list, etc.) and the assignment didn't take place? Exceptions *never* are recoverable, that's what exceptions are for.

Comment: @BrechtMachiels: Don't use exceptions for out-of-band communication. Make your coroutine a class instance instead, and add flags to that instance to communicate OOB info.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exceptions can be used for control flow (exceptional cases), but I get the idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wouldn't say exceptions are never recoverable, recovering from errors is obviously one reason to use `except`. What I think you're trying to say (and I agree) is that it's not possible to automatically recover from exceptions.

Comment: @delnan: You cannot resume the block that the exception was thrown in, I meant. :-) If you *ignore* an exception in a given block then that block's execution context is gone and cannot be recovered.